# Unique index or primary key violation error despite data being inserted

Tags: java, h2

I'm trying to implement a users authentication table. I'm on user registration and my console prints out:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.USERS_USERNAME_UINDEX ON PUBLIC.USERS(USERNAME) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
> INSERT INTO USERS(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?,?,?) [23505-200]

I don't really understand why. My table's SQL script is as follows:

```sql
-- auto-generated definition
create table USERS
(
    USER_ID    INT auto_increment,
    USERNAME   VARCHAR2,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2,
    LAST_NAME  VARCHAR2,
    PASSWORD   VARCHAR2,
    constraint USERS_PK
        primary key (USER_ID)
);

create unique index USERS_USERNAME_UINDEX
    on USERS (USERNAME);

create unique index USERS_USER_ID_UINDEX
    on USERS (USER_ID);
```

I want `username` to be unique for each entry so I set that field as unique. This is how I populate it:

```java
Connection connection = new InitialiseDatabase().getConnection();
String sql = "INSERT INTO USERS(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement myStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
myStatement.setString(1, txtFirstName.getText().trim());
myStatement.setString(2, txtLastName.getText().trim());
myStatement.setString(3, txtUsername.getText().trim());
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(txtPassword.getText(), BCrypt.gensalt());
myStatement.setString(4, hashed);
myStatement.executeUpdate();
```

How can I get around this?

My table is being populated with the data though. So I don't understand what exactly is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you find the data in the database despite this error message, then that probably means that you somehow try to execute the same insert twice (the first will succeed and the second will show this error). Either because you entered the same data twice or you somehow call this method twice.

Comment: I'm calling that method once though, and my database is empty, I get that when I try to insert the first row in the first table of my database. Which it does populate, but I delete the row and try again and I get the same

Answer (score 0):

A UNIQUE index makes sure that two rows cannot have same value for the unique indexed column.
https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-index/oracle-unique-index/

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.USERS_USERNAME_UINDEX ON PUBLIC.USERS(USERNAME)
```

is pretty much talking. You're probably inserting a new row with a same value of username already inserted previously.

> My table is being populated with the data though

Make sure your DB does not already have same value you're trying to insert.

Comment: My database is empty. I clear all records before I enter. So I get that error upon inserting the FIRST row. I deleted it, then when I try to reneter again, then I get that also